# Can ping but received "Remote side unexpectedly closed connection" on latest version of putty SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I understand that this is a duplicate question, however, in the other questions, the solution does not apply to my circumstance.

I'm currently using the latest version of PuTTY, 0.73 on Windows.

I am trying to SSH into an address but I keep receiving the error `"Remote side unexpectedly closed connection"`, even before I am able to enter my login credentials.

However, I am able to successfully ping using the command prompt.

Comment: We lack certain information to help you perfectly. I did attempt to answer your question, but I had to make assumptions due to the lack of information. For example, is all in a network or over the internet? What OS's are you using on both server and client side? Has it worked before, or is it a new config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging is definitely not the same as SSH into a server.

A ping only means that the other side acknowledges an ICMP request. This could be done by a router, and not the SSH server itself even.

When it comes to SSH into a server, the server itself has to actually have SSH setup and configured properly before this can work. This means that its SSH deamon must be up and running (including all necessary services) and the firewall must be configured to allow all traffic to pass through.

If the firewall were to block the connection, it would timeout. You do not specify how quickly the message comes to know if this is a time-out or not.

If the message is coming quickly, then the SSH services are not running or another config issue on the server side arises.

Lastly, if it gives a timeout, but it still does that with the firewall temporarily disabled, either there is another firewall in place, or you specify the wrong port, the port forwarding is not setup correctly, you connect to the wrong hostname or another client-side config error occurs.